# Compare rows with a column value

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve all rows with a ID which have a specific value in the other column.

The database looks like this:

[image: Database Illustration]

I want to retrieve those rows which have a VAL of 2 and the corresponding ID rows. So in this case this would give me all the ID 1 rows and the ID 3 row:

[image: Database Illustration 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is exists:

```
select t.*
from test t
where exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.val = 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

you'll need a subquery (or join or cte or derived table) Subquery is easist to visualise

Select * from Test where ID IN
(SELECT ID from Test where VAL = 2)

Answer (score 1):

Constructions like `where id in (select id from ...)` and `where exists (select 1 from ...)` may take very long time, because for every row in `test` you are executing subquery. To solve your problem you can join `test` with itself and make `distinct` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM test t1
     INNER JOIN test t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.val = 2
```

Comment: Why would a join be faster than a correlated subquery? The database still has to search matching IDs for every ID, and in this query, there is the additional step of searching for duplicates.

Comment: Yes, database still has to search matching IDs for every ID, but executing subquery in where-clause cause additional overhead, isn't it? Every row in table requires execution of subquery. Database simple inner join implementation will be faster than execution subquery for every row. Maybe sqlite optimizer is so smart and optimize these queryies to identical execution plans.

Comment: P.S. DISTINCT may be replaced with GROUP BY. And if it is so critical, it is possible to join table with subquery, which returns IDs with VAL=2

Comment: Both the subquery and the join require lookups in the second table, so the execution plan is indeed pretty much the same (except that the join does not stop after the first row found). As for DISTINCT and GROUP BY, they do the same thing, so they are implemented in the same way.

Comment: Huh, you're right, my fault) Thanks for reply. I've tested these queries in my PostgreSQL and I've got suprising result. I was always thinking that subqueries in where-clause is evil, but actually as I can see it is not always true.